# RecylerView Scrolling issue data has been changed when recylerview scroll up and down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have attached 2 images of my app, first one is the normal image. But when I am scrolling the `recyclerView` the data is changed, look at the second image for that.

Here is when it is normal[image]

After I scroll up and down 
[image]

here is my MainActivity.java Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  final String android_versions[]={
            "0",
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8",
            "9",
            "10",
            "11",
            "12",
            "13",
            "14",
            "15",
            "16",
            "17",
            "18",
            "19",
            "20",
            "14",
            "15",
            "16",
            "17",
            "18",
            "19",
            "20"

    };
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylerview);
        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this,android_versions);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


    }



}
```

Here is Recylerview Adapter Code

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {



    Context mcontext;
    String[] data;
    int counter = 1;

    public ItemAdapter(Context mcontext, String[] data) {
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(data[position]);
        if (counter == 1) {
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            counter = 2;
            holder.textView.setText("1");
        } else if (counter == 2) {
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            counter = 3;
            holder.textView.setText("2");
        } else if (counter == 3) {
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            counter = 1;
            holder.textView.setText("3");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
}
```

Why this is happening when I am scrolling items in `recylerview`. Kindly guide me for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Both images look same to me. Have you by mistake posted same image twice ?

Comment: yes i have edit question sorry fot that look once again

Comment: try adding a final else condition in your if-else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable like `counter` to get the position of your item's position in RecyclerView. You have to use the position variable provided in the `onBindViewHolder()` method of have a consistent behavior.

In short, you have to decide how your view should look using the `position` variable inside `onBindViewHolder()` method.

If you want to make 1st layout red and text `1` and so on, you can use something like this inside `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
    int modulus = position % 3;
    switch (modulus){

        case 0:
            //handle logic for red
            break;
        case 1:
            //handle logic for green
            break;
        default:
            //handle logic for blue

    }
```

Comment: @Jaspal happy to help. consider accepting the solution too :)

Answer (score 1):

Before we solve this problem lets try to understand how recycler-view works.

Recycler view creates a pool of views and binds data to those views.

now when you start scrolling instead of inflating new views it reuses views not visible to the user

now in your onBindViewHolder you are changing counter as you scroll up and down.
Hence when you reach top again counter has already changed and when dataBinding is done some thing new comes up

so instead of that try this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(data[position]);
    int type = Integer.parseInt(data[position]);
    if (type%3 == 1) {
        holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        holder.textView.setText("1");
    } else if (type%3 == 2) {
        holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        holder.textView.setText("2");
    } else if (type%3 == 0) {
        holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        holder.textView.setText("3");
    }
}
```

I guess it would work fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a model class for your list like this

```
public class AndroidVersions{
  String version;
  int color;
  // create constructor and getter setter for both 
}
```

now create a list of using this class

```
ArrayList<AndroidVersions> android_versions = new ArrayList();
```

add values like

```
android_versions.add(new AndroidVersions("0", Color.RED));
android_versions.add(new AndroidVersions("1", Color.GREEN));
android_versions.add(new AndroidVersions("2", Color.BLUE));
.
.
.
.
```

and pass this in `recyclerView`

in recyclerView write code like this

```
holder.textView.setText(data[position]);
  holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(list.get(position).getColor());
  holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).getVersion());
}
```